# Dynamically position a div in the top left of a resizable element in JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm creating a custom style for the Draggable interface of the JQuery UI you can see here:

http://psdesignzone.com/help/Designer.html

I'm having trouble getting the NW-Resize section working right, if you look at the top left of the box (e.g. the North West Resizable class) you'll see that it's positioned relatively at the start and looks good, but when you resize the box it get's all messed up.

I can't think of a way to get it to always positioned in the right place (because this is dynamically generated I can't change the actual HTML either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick. On `.ui-resizable-nw` change `position:relative` to `position:absolute` and change `top:-166px` to `top:-10px`.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/DNnSm/

```
.ui-resizable-nw {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
    position: absolute; /* changed from relative */
    top: -10px; /* changed from -166px */
    left: -10px;
    cursor: nw-resize;
}
```

Comment: Wow that does work, I didn't expect that but I guess with JQuery's resizing functions it allows absolute positioning to work like a charm.  Thanks!